# Is Ubuntu vulnerable to recent exploits using USB sticks and automount?

Tags: security, automount

I [read recently](http://lwn.net/Articles/426395/) that someone demonstrated a security attack on a PC via the use of automount and a USB stick.

How vulnerable am I to this attack and what steps are developers doing to be proactive against this sort of thing?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You're not vulnerable to the specific attack, but the approach is very interesting. The vulnerabilities used are [already fixed](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-1035-1).

I've been chatting with Jon Larimer since I heard about his [presentation at Shmoo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ovfYBa1EHm4#t=90). The defeat of ASLR takes
quite a while (Larimer is brute-forcing it on an NX-emu 32bit system
-- a relatively easy target -- and for the demo he disabled ASLR to show
it more quickly), and at the time hadn't found a workable way to bypass
AppArmor (which he also turned off for the demo), so this speaks pretty
well to the proactive defenses in Ubuntu. Using 64bit would have made the attack unfeasible.

Regardless, we took the opportunity to [ask](https://launchpad.net/bugs/714958) the Desktop team to find
a way to disable auto-mounting when the screen is locked to avoid this
kind of "local but unauthenticated" attack, and have been reviewing
improvements to the other thumbnailers (adding ASLR and AppArmor
profiles).

I've actually written about it [here](http://www.outflux.net/blog/archives/2011/02/11/shaping-the-direction-of-research/) for people interested in more details.

Comment: Does it set no execute on mount of removable media?